# How to preform a summation on a summation in the denomimator?

Tags: statistics, summation

Given that

$$k_i = \frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} , $$

I need to prove that

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n k_i = 0 . $$

My question is, how do I perform a summation of the summation (sum of differences) in the denominator? I have no idea how to evaluate it in it's current form.

Comment: Take a look at this reference on [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and edit your question so it's clearer what you mean. As for the question itself, if you want to prove that a fraction is equal to 0, generally, you just need to prove that the numerator is 0 and the denominator is nonzero. If that's true, then you're done.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, edited it for clarity. So can I just apply the summation onto the numerator and prove its zero. For the denominator do I still have to apply the summation?

Comment: As long as you don't have $x_i = \bar{x}$ for all $i$, it's nonzero and you can multiply both sides of your equation by that denominator and it will go away, so there's no need to evaluate it. Then, you just need to show that $\sum (x_i - \bar{x}) = 0$, and the key to that is to think about the relationship between $\bar{x}$ and $\sum x_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

If there's at least one $x_i \neq \bar{x}$, then you have

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \neq 0 , $$

so you can factor out that denominator:

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} = \frac{1}{{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}*\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x}) .$$

Your next hint:

$$ \bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}*\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \Rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i = n \bar{x} .$$

Comment: Thank you kindly Amaan. After setting the denominator /= to zero, I set the sum of derivations equal to zero and proved that :)

Comment: Of course, and for future reference, if you have to compute multiple sums, work your way from the inside out. It's kind of like performing operations in parentheses in the interior of an expression, so you'd just evaluate the sum in the denominator, then evaluate the exterior sum.